# Excel VBA Overflows when dividing two Doubles

Tags: vba, excel, office-2010

I'm getting an Overflow error when I try to divide two doubles, and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code as it is now

```
'x will be used to sum the elements  
Dim x, ct As Double
x = 0
ct = 0
For Each cell In Range(rng)
    If cell.Offset(, offset1).Value = Crit1 And cell.Offset(, offset2).Value = Crit2 Then
        x = x + cell.Value
        ct = ct + 1
    End If
Next

'Divide by count
Avg = x / ct
```

At first, `ct` was declared as `Long`, but I changed it to `Double` to see if that might fix it, but it didn't.

I've also tried changing the last line to `Avg = CDbl(x / ct)`, but I get the same error.

The values in `cell.Value` will always be real numbers, usually ranging between 0 and about 9,000,000, occasionally going up as high as 17,000,000. The numbers greater than about 20,000 are almost always integers.

Comment: You need to trap the values causing the overflow. Keep a breakpoint in your code and when it throws an error watch the variables to see why that's happening. It depends on the data in there, but you need to make the code 'safer' by adding some sort of error trap or pre-check the data before dividing (check for a 0 denominator, etc.)

Comment: @hnk Thanks! I'd forgotten to check for a 0 denominator, and that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's divide by zero error. VBA just reported it as "overflow".

Comment: Thanks! I'd forgotten to check for that.